# IntentService not affected by sleep or doze on emulator

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice, android-intentservice, android-wake-lock

I want to test the effects of screen-off and doze-mode on `IntentService`.

For this, I start a background `IntentService` on Android Marshmallow, deactivate the emulated charger, set the emulator to "discharging" and turn the screen off.
I don't apply any wake lock. However, my IntentService never gets interrupted. It just keeps running and running and one `onHandleIntent` gets executed after another.
What I expect instead is, that when I turn the screen off or when the device goes into doze, the `IntentService` should be destroyed. Is this assumption not correct?
Is my emulator not simulating sleep/doze properly or why is my `IntentService` not affected?

```
public class ExampleService extends IntentService {
    public static final String TAG = "IntentService";

    public ExampleService() {
        super("bla");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent");
        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");

        runInBackground(input);
    }


    private void runInBackground(String input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, input + " " + i);
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }
}
```

I start this `IntentService` from my `MainActivity` multiple times so it runs for about **30-60 min**:

```
public void startService(View v) {
    String input = editTextInput.getText().toString();

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", input);

    startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is my emulator not simulating sleep/doze properly or why is my
>   IntentService not affected?

It seems your emulator is not turned to doze mode.

> the IntentService should be destroyed

no. Service will be suspended but not destroyed entirely

Try following steps:

1. Ensure you configure emulator with android 6 or higher
2. Run app, lock device
3. Enable doze mode using ADB command
   $adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle

See the official documentation about 'doze mode' and 'stand-by' conditions 
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Comment: The command line tool says "Now forced into idle mode" but it still behaves the same

Comment: I can confirm that my device is in doze because Jobs get deferred immediately. Just my IntentService keeps running and running